# .net 4.0.1 converted to platform 4.5 after installing visual studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I just installed visual studio 2012 side by side with visual studio 2010.
If I created a project targeting .net 4.0.1, and build, the project now targets .net 4.5 which it should not do.

Is this a bug in a targets file or?

Comment: It isn't very clear how you *know* it targets 4.5.  .NET 4.5 is a *replacement* for 4.0, not a side-by-side version, so if you installed VS2012 then you no longer have .NET 4.0.  But you certainly still have the 4.0 reference assemblies.  An assembly built with VS2012 with .NET 4.5 selected as the target platform still targets runtime version 4.0.30319

Comment: Not bug. Landmine. -> [Read about it.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a) <-

Comment: READ THE COMMENT WITH THE LINK IN IT. It contains the answer to your question. A moderator moved it from Answer to comment.